# AngularJS Enable / Disable Dropdown based on the variable

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have a Dropdown on the CreateTask.cshtml page as below.

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="analysisType" name="analysisType" ng-model="vm.analysisType" ng-options="analysistype.typeID as analysistype.typeName for analysistype in vm.analysisTypes" placeholder="Choose analysis type " required><option value=""></option></select>
```

Here I am setting a variable value conditionally to true or false on CreateTask.JS file.

```
vm.isNewTask =true;
```

If NewTask, the Dropdown should be enabled. If not NewTask, this Dropdown will be defaulted  to a value and should be disabled.
I tried

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive.

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="analysisType" name="analysisType"
        ng-model="vm.analysisType"
        ng-options="analysistype.typeID as analysistype.typeName for analysistype in vm.analysisTypes" 
        ng-disabled="!vm.isNewTask" placeholder="Choose analysis type "
        required>
   <option value=""></option>
</select>
```